# Snapchat-like jquery color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors

I'm interested in creating a color picker like the one found in iOS Snapchat. It's a very nice slim vertical bar, which I'd like to be horizontal, [seen here](http://www.insidemobileapps.com/wp-content/uploads/IMG_2051.png).

I've been using individual boxes like this, but would much rather have a slider/gradient like Snapchat's:

js:

```
    $(function() {
    $.each(['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0', '#0ff', '#00f', '#000', '#fff'], function() {
        $('#tools').append("<a href='#colored_sketch' data-color='" + this + "' style='border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: " + this + "; display: inline-block;'></a> ");
    });
```

html:

```
        <div id='tools'></div>
```

Every example color picker I've seen is a recreation of Adobe's color chooser, which is way too big for my work area and I haven't found something small enough with a sliding gradient like Snapchats. Any help in recreating it much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a slider (e.g. jQuery UI) and then the color simply is `hsl(slider * 360, 100%, 50%)` (assuming the slider returns values from [0,1]).

If you need to you can then convert this back to rgb.

http://jsbin.com/utumab/1/edit

It's vertical (didn't read you want it horizontal). But it's trivial to change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm sorry though, could you show an example in a fiddle? I went and messed with the jQuery UI sliders, but don't understand your comment, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Prinzhorn, got it! Here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/t2PDc/1/  (background image isn't loading for some reason)